# Load custom view instead of default view in iOS app

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I have some problem in creating View(must open at start of app) in already existing project.

I have project from https://github.com/emysa341/Login-with-gmail-google-g--using-oath-2.0-protocol , when i run this project it directly goes to login page but i need to change that to home screen. i.e when i click on button in first view then it has to go to login page.

I tried creating .h,.m and .xib file and tried to load these files first as soon as app starts but i am not getting that.

Just tell me process "How to create .xib file in an existing project and make that xib(created by me,not default) to load first?". I googled but no perfect solution.I tried changing code in appdelegate.m but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method of appDelegate add this line

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    YourViewController *yourViewController=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]yourViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController=self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got solution from your answer by making little changes according to my requirements. Any how i got the concept behind this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, you set the first view there.  Just open the .storyboard file in Xcode, and there should be an arrow that is faded out on one end, and the head of the arrow should be pointing to a view controller.  Just click-and-drag that arrow to the view controller you want to show first, and you should be good to go.

Alternatively (still in the .storyboard file), select a view controller and in the Attributes Inspector there is a checkbox for "Is Initial View Controller" - check that box for the view you want to show up first.